# Layout with background corner radius with elements inside

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with a custom background with corner radius

[image]

The code of the drawable background is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"
/>
<stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dusky_blue"/>
<solid
    android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

When I set a background color of an element inside this layout, the corners of the parent are overlapped.

[image]

Is there a simple way to fit the child background to the parent corner (without making a customer drawable background) ?

Thank you

Comment: pls share your layout xml code

Comment: Make round corners to the tabLayout container

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the background directly because it's not a simple Drawable.
You can use `android:backgroundTint="#000"` in XML, you can also try these java methods

```
public static void changeGradientDrawableBackgroundColor(View view, int color) {
    GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
    gd.setColor(color);
}

public static void changeStrokeColor(View view, int color) {
    GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
    gd.setStroke(2, color);
}

public static void changeTransitionDrawableColor(TransitionDrawable td, int color, int index) {
    td.getDrawable(index).setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

or you can simply use this library for making rounded corner layouts

[Rounded Korner Layouts](https://github.com/JcMinarro/RoundKornerLayouts)

Answer (score 0):

Your stroke width is 1dp:

```
<stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/dusky_blue"/>
```

With that being said, it looks like you would need to add a padding of 1dp or more to your tab layout so that your border isn't covered by your content background.  So the element backgrounds will begin at least 1dp inside of your tab layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
    *Follow the blew steps to do the expected output...*   

  left_bg.xml
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                  <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                  <stroke android:width="1dp"
                          android:color="#00000000" />

                  <corners android:topLeftRad`enter code here`ius="10dp"
                           android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
                  <padding android:left="0dp"
                           android:top="0dp"
                           android:right="0dp"
                           android:bottom="0dp" />
              </shape>

 right_bg.xml
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                  <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                  <stroke android:width="1dp"
                          android:color="#00000000" />

                  <corners android:topRightRadius="10dp"
                           android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
                  <padding android:left="0dp"
                           android:top="0dp"
                           android:right="0dp"
                           android:bottom="0dp" />
              </shape>


        *Layout design*
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:weightSum="2"
                      android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
                      android:layout_margin="10dp"
                      android:id="@+id/llIeltsSocreType">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAcademicScore"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:text="Academic"
                      android:textColor="#fff"
                      android:background="@drawable/left_bg"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:textSize="25sp"/>


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGeneralScore"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                      android:layout_height="50dp"
                      android:text="General"
                      android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:textSize="25sp"
                      android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>


programmatically manage your click event and set your layout corner and background with text color



               if(getSharedString(select_type).equals("academic")  ){
                tvAcademicScore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.left_bg)
                tvGeneralScore.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorTransparent)

                tvAcademicScore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorWhite))
                tvGeneralScore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))

            }else if(getSharedString(select_type).equals("general")){
                tvAcademicScore.setBackgroundResource( R.color.colorTransparent)
                tvGeneralScore.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.right_bg)

                tvGeneralScore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorWhite))
                tvAcademicScore.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your issue

Instead of setting background color create two other xml in drawable and set it in the background when required.

Example :

1. left_curve_shape.xml

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
       android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="7dp"/>
   <solid
       android:color="@color/your_color_name"/>
   </shape>`
2. right_curve_shape.xml

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
       android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
   <solid
       android:color="@color/your_color_name"/>
   </shape>`

And Now Finally

Set these drawables instead of color like

```
android:background="@drawable/left_curve_shape"
android:background="@drawable/right_curve_shape"
```

You can also set background from java code.

Hope it will fix your issue